# Fullcalendar - get the selected date by click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm using fullcaledar.io as a gem https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails I want to get a selected by click on a button:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //........
    // creating fullcalendar
    //..........

    $('#btn').click(function() {
        var a = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate').toDate();

      });
   });
```

For some reason it returns the current date: `Tue Apr 21 2015 16:13:48 GMT+0700 (ICT)`, not the selected one. Why is that?

Comment: you can use https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: What do you mean by "selected date"?  Are you using the selectable feature which is disabled by default?  Or do you mean the date range that the full calendar is currently displaying?

Comment: @TravisCollins, selected cell.

Comment: Sorry, this did not clarify  the question.  "Selected cell" could mean a few different things in fullcalendar.  If you showed the "//creating fullcalendar" code, it would perhaps clarify if you're talking about the "selectable: true" feature, or if you're referring to the currently displayed date range, or something else.

Comment: Are you clicking on a Day? Or is the button outside of fullcalendar? If you are clicking on a Day, is it in month or day view?